# Alert user the page is closing, except when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onbeforeunload

I'm using the following example to prevent users from inadvertently closing their tab or window.   The problem is that it continues to prompt when my form is submitted.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  //IE & Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are you sure?';
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Here's the form:

```
                        <script language='javascript'>

                            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) 
                            {
                                var e = e || window.event;
                                //IE & Firefox
                                if (e) 
                                {
                                    e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
                                }
                                // For Safari
                                return 'Sure?';
                            };

                            function checkForm(theForm)
                            {
                                if (mytext!='anytext')
                                {
                                    window.nounloadcheck = false;

                                    return false;
                                }

                            }

                        </script>

<form  action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='post' onSubmit='window.nounloadcheck = true; return checkForm(this)'>
<input type='text' name='mytext' value='anytext'>
<input type='submit' name='submit_data' value='Submit Answers' />
</form>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LLbe/) showing the problem.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set a flag to not run the onbeforeunload in the onSubmit, but you never check for it in your onbeforeunload handler.

Comment: yep, I see what I am missing now.  Added some code to check for the flag, it's working now.  If you want to put this as an answer I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @acoder: Two more things to check: 1. Is `checkForm()` being called? 2. Does `mytext` contain the value of the input field? In your fiddle, both `checkForm` and `mytext` cause errors because they are undefined.